# Is there a generalized analogue to the summation and product operators?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

The summation operator ($\sum$) and the product operator ($\prod$) will take a sequence of values and sum or multiply them.

Is there a general operator that will take a sequence of values and repeatedly apply a binary function to them?

Something, such that:

$\xi_{n=0}^5 S_n = f(S_5,\xi_{n=0}^4S_n)$

$\xi_{n=0}^5 S_n = f(S_5,f(S_4, \xi_{n=0}^3S_n))$

$...$

$\xi_{n=0}^5 S_n = f(S_5,f(S_4,f(S_3,f(S_2,f(S_1,f(S_0, I_f))))))$

Where $I_f$ is the identity value for the operation in question.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Given a map $f$, a sequence $(S_n)$ and starting value $I_\xi$ you *already defined* yourself the meaning of $\xi_{n=0}^5 S_n$, so what's the question? I just note here that such a procedure called *right folding* in functional programming languages. For example, in Haskell sum can be defined as `foldr (+) 0`, here `(+)` is $f$ and `0` is $I_\xi$.

Comment: My question is, rather than defining my own operator, is there a standard one in the field of mathematics? As you've surmised, I'm basically asking, what's the mathematical equivalent of the `fold` or `reduce` function in functional languages?

Comment: For clarity, I changed $I_\xi$ to $I_f$. @CanisLupus commented before I made the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I was looking for an [iterated binary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_binary_operation) which is denoted by

> $f/(a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$

Answer (score 0):

You need an associative binary operation for unambiguous meaning: otherwise for each way of inserting parenthesis one will get a different answer. If the individual entities are sets one can consider union, and intersections for them.

Also one needs a convention for what is the value for empty operation (that is, when the set  of terms being 'summed' or 'multiplied' is empty).

In numbers one can talk of gcd of n numbers, lcm of n numbers.

So in any semigroup one can talk of this.

Comment: The operation does not need to be associative as the order of a sequence is fixed and so the order of application is fixed.
The empty operation should return the identity value for the binary operation... this is the behaviour for the empty sum and the empty product. It's also the behaviour shown by $\forall$ (vacuous truth), since $\top$ is the identity for $\land$

Comment: If your question is  knowing if there is notation the answer is simple: introduce your own. Or alternatively look at LaTeX symbol list for *operators", e.g., bigcup, bigcap, bigoplus, Non-associtative is fine once you fix the order of operation.

Comment: I'd be happy to introduce my own if there is no standard notation; before I do that, I figured I'd post a question to see if there *is* a standard notation.